# Wordpress - Is it possible to do a request to the wordpress database from a page html block?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress.org and I figured out that I can add HTML, CSS and Javascript to a page via a code block. But my question is, can I also make a call to the WordPress database from a page? Or do I need to make a plugin for that?

Comment: Yes. WordPress is entirely built on calls to the database from pages/posts/custom content.

Comment: What exactly do you want to query from inside post/page content?

Comment: Would I do that with javascript and ajax?

Comment: @TomUkelove i'm trying to get a taxonomy from a custom post type and make a dependent dropdown with parent and children. So the first dropdown will be the parents and the second the children.

Comment: Also can I run php in a html block? I tried to echo something but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a shortcode that calls a php function in your (child-themes) functions.php.

This is a good guide to start from:

https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-a-shortcode-in-wordpress/

```
// function that runs when shortcode is called
function wpb_demo_shortcode() { 

// Things that you want to do. 
$message = 'Hello world!'; 

// Output needs to be return
return $message;
} 
// register shortcode
add_shortcode('greeting', 'wpb_demo_shortcode');
```

And then call it within your post/page (in a Gutenberg shortcode block)

```
[greeting]
```

This is a good way because you can re-use and maintain it easily.

Tom

Comment: If someone looks at this answer in the future you can also add parameters https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

Using page you can call database you can do it using

- Creating a template and assign that template in wordpress page
- Or you can create short code in function.php and add shortcode in your wordpress page

Create page template

1) Create file in your theme folder and name it 'custom.php' you can name it anything.

2) Open file and add this

3) Start editing in that page you can call database using

```
   global $wpdb;
   $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_posts LIMIT 10');
```

4) After editing 'custom.php' you can assign this template in your custom page

[image]

note: please refer this link to know more about page template 
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/creating-custom-page-template-in-wordpress/

Create short code in function.php

1) You can create shortcode using

```
// function that runs when shortcode is called
function wpb_demo_shortcode() { 

   global $wpdb;
   $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_posts LIMIT 10');

return $result;
} 
// register shortcode
add_shortcode('get_post_shortcode', 'wpb_demo_shortcode');
```

2) you can call shortcode in any page of wordpress.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[get_post_shortcode]"); ?>
```